# Prove that $(ϕ^n )' (α) = \prod_{ i=0}^{n-1}ϕ'( ϕ^i (α)) $

Tags: calculus, functions, taylor-expansion, dynamical-systems, arithmetic-dynamics

> Prove that $\displaystyle (\phi^n )' (\alpha) = \prod_{ i=0}^{n-1}\phi'( \phi^i (\alpha)) $ .

In particular, $\alpha$ is a critical point of $\phi^n$ if and only if one of the points $\alpha, \phi(\alpha), \ldots , \phi^{n−1} (\alpha)$ is a critical point of $\phi$.

$\phi(z) \in \Bbb C(z)$ is a rational function and $\phi'(z)$ is the derivative of $\phi(z)$
Here $\phi^n=\phi\circ \ldots \circ \phi\ \text{($n$ times)}$

I was thinking that whether I have to use Taylor's theorem or not to prove the highlighted line or not.

As if we take the highlighted line to be true then:

$α$ is a critical point of $\phi^n$ iff $\displaystyle (\phi^n )' (\alpha)=0=\prod_{ i=0}^{n-1}\phi'( \phi^i (\alpha))$ iff $ \phi'( \phi^i (\alpha))=0$ for some $i$ iff one of $\alpha, \phi(\alpha), \ldots , \phi^{n−1} (\alpha)$ is a critical point of $\phi$.

Can you help me in proving the highlighted line?

Comment: This is just the chain rule.